# Svelte How to Conditionally Display wrapping element in Parent depending on Child component's variable?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a child Button that I want to reuse. This button contains the code to check whether the user has permissions to use the Button. In one parent, I just want to display the button as is, and this works fine. However in a different component, I want to wrap the button in a Card, and conditionally display both the Card and the Button depending on whether the user is authorized.

Child Component:

```
<script>
    let isAuthorized = false;

    async function updateIsAuthorized() {
        isAuthorized = await hasPermission('CREATE_FOO');
    }

    onMount(isAuthorized);
</script>

{#if isAuthorized}
    <Button>...</Button>
{/if}
```

The following Parent of course will display an empty Card if the user doesn't have permissions to use the Button. Instead, I want to hide the Card in this case, so this is no good:

```
<script>
    import FooButton from './FooButton.svelte';
    // ...

</script>

<Card>
    <FooButton>
</Card>
```

I did try adding an isAuthorized boolean to the parent (and export let isAuthorized to the child), and binding it, but this does not work:

```
<script>
    import FooButton from './FooButton.svelte';
    // ...
    let isAuthorized = false;
</script>

{#if isAuthorized}
    <Card>
        <FooButton bind:isAuthorized>
    </Card>
{/if}
```

I assume the problem here is that becuase `isAuthorized` default to false, the `FooButton` is never rendered, so the child component never has a chance to modify the bound `isAuthorized`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really elegant solution to this, as you would be wrapping the button based on a state that is internal to this button.

The only way I see for solving this is to flip the entire thing around and extend your Button component to be able to render the Card itself (depending on some flag perhaps).

```html
<script>
  export let isCard = false;
  let isAuthorized
</sccript>

{#if isAuthorized}
  {#if isCard}
    <Card>
     <button>...</button>
    </Card>
  {:else}
    <button>...</button>
  {/if}
{/if}
```

You could make this slightly more dynamic if you allow passing in a component as the 'Card'

```html
<script>
  export let cardComponent;
  let isAuthorized
</script>

{#if isAuthorized}
  {#if cardComponent}
    <svelte:component this={cardComponent}>
      <button>...</button>
    </svelte:component>
  {:else}
     <button>...</button>
  {/if}
{/if}
```

In the last case the usage would be something like:

```html
<script>
  import Button from '...';
  import Card from '...';
</script>

<Button cardComponent={Card} />
```

with `Card` the card you want to show, with a `<slot>` element where the button should go.